# Automatically provisioning an instance to connect to a database cluster endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am looking for a way to provision an instance with a configuration file that contains the endpoints to connect to a database cluster in an automatic way, using terraform. I am using a `aws_rds_cluster` resource, from which I can get the endpoint using the expression `aws_rds_cluster.my-cluster.endpoint`. Then, I would like to provision machines instantiated with an `aws_instance` resource so that the value of that expression is stored in the file `/DBConfig.sh`.

The content of the `DBConfig.sh` file would look like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

ENDPOINT=<$aws_rds_cluster.my-cluster.endpoint$>
READER_ENDPOINT=<$aws_rds_cluster.my-cluster.reader_endpoint$>
```

Truth be told, once I successfully reach that point, I'd like to be able to do the same thing for machines created by a `aws_launch_configuration` resource.

Is this something that can be done with terraform? If not, what other tools can I use to achieve this kind of automation? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways which can achieve that. I think all of the would involve [user_data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

For example, you could have `aws_instance` with the `user_data` as follows:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {

  # other atrributes
  
  user_data = <<-EOL
  #!/bin/bash
  
  cat >./DBConfig.sh <<-EOL2
  #!/bin/bash
  ENDPOINT=${aws_rds_cluster.my-cluster.endpoint}
  READER_ENDPOINT=${aws_rds_cluster.my-cluster.reader_endpoint}
  EOL2
  
  chmod +x ./DBConfig.sh
  
  EOL
}
```

The above will launch an istance which will have `DBConfig.sh` with resolved values of the endpoints in its root (`/`) directory.

Comment: Thank you. I have come to realize that there is also a `user_data` attribute on `aws_launch_configuration` and `aws_launch_template` resources. It means there is no need for a convoluted ami derivation.

Comment: @Dalzhim Yes. Don't always need AMI. But custom AMI are still useful especially if you have lots of dependencies to install in user_data. With custom AMI you can save a lot of time on provisioning your instances in this case.